# Cannot remove partitions - losing disk space

Tags: windows, partitioning, sd-card

I am using Windows 7 Pro, I have a 2GB micro SD card which I put a Arch Linux image (iso) on using win32diskimager. _ I no longer care about the iso image or any contents on this drive, I want it clean

Navigating to My Computer -> J:\ shows I have only 90MB of space available.
I have tried formatting multiple times and also changing the filesystem but the result is the same.

I have opened the Disk Partition manager in Windows and can see the SD drive is partitioned into what appear to be 3 parts.

I was able to delete the middle partition visible in the screenshot I have posted below, however after doing this it just changed to "Free Space", I have also edited my image to show the result of the right click options available on each part of the drivespace.

Ideally I want my SD drive back to 1 single partition with all space available (usually around 1.86GB out of the total 2GB if I remember correctly)

[image]

Comment: You want to delete everything on it in order to use it fully again?

Comment: @davidbaumann Yes

Comment: Can you mark something as solution?

Answer (score 1):

If Windows does not allow you to extend the first partition (not sure it can do that on-the-fly with FAT partitions), you should erase **all** the partitions on the SD card (meaning that you will lose all the data on it, so copy it somewhere else before), then create a new empty partition taking the whole space on the card. This should solve your problem.

Also, the green zone marked "free space" on your image looks like an empty extended partition. You should delete it before being able to extend the first (primary) partition to the whole card, or to create a single big partition.

**EDIT**: I forgot that Windows does not like multiple partitions on removable devices. One thing you can do is to use again Win32DiskImager, put disk image having a single partition on the SD card (**beware**: it will **destroy** your data, copy the contents of the SD card elsewhere before you proceed!), and then go back to the partition manager to delete that partition and make one filling the card. I just made an image of a 32MB SD card with a single empty partition here: https://drive.switch.ch/public.php?service=files&t=2b8d361662303d6a01b9ac5aa1107f30 (39 kB compressed ZIP).

Comment: I dont see how I can do this, I do not appear to have the option anywhere to *erase all partitions*. As for the green free space partition, that also doesnt appear to have a delete option

Comment: I forgot that Windows does not like multiple partitions on removable devices... I'll edit the answer with another solution. Or see the answer by @davidbaumann if you have Linux box that you can use for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Attention! Overwriting the wrong disk will lead to a data loss!**

You can connect it to a linux pc, or boot linux from DVD or thumbdrive.

Then you find out, where to find the sd card:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Let's say, it's `/dev/sdc`, you will find it easy as it should be the only device with 2GB in size.
Now we just overwrite the first 50 MB with zeros.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=10M count=5
sync
```

Reboot and you are almost finished: Windows will handle it like a new device and ask you to format it.

Comment: I do not have a linux pc around... Is this seriuosly the only way to do it? WIndows doesnt have any control? If its the case windows sucks

Comment: Linux brings so many tools by default, so I only know them.
I am sure there's a windows tool for something like that, but as Linux gives me the tool, which I can use for so many things, I don't want to use tools that might bring malware or adware.

Comment: A live Linux on a CD or USB stick (even if you only use Windows!) might be very handy to have around, to solve problems of any type, especially when it gets to low-level stuff that Windows will not let you do (e.g., partitioning a removable device...).